# All PHP pages are blank with Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Here's the output in error.log. I tried to paste it in stackoverflow but I couldn't get it to come out "readable"

http://pastebin.com/cpTgSw6R

Apache server loads, even phpmyadmin loads. But any other php script I have doesn't load.

Comment: I think this question belongs to `superuser`.

Comment: What? Who's superuser?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: search for "error_reporting" in your script , change error_reporting( ..... ) to error_reporting(E_ALL) . If not exists, add it. For detailed debugs, use xdebug. Uncomment lines in php.ini under [XDebug] tag.

Comment: What is the URL you're using to hit your PHP scripts?  Where are the PHP scripts located?  Are there any .htaccess rewrites happening?  Do the other Apache logs provide any information?